# Write non-ASCII characters to stdin of a progam on a tty (over ssh)

Tags: c, terminal, binary, reverse-engineering, tty

I'm SSHd into a remote server with some binary challenges.

At one point it asks for me to input text. I know it's using `fgets()` to read `stdin`, and that I can overflow where it is being copied to and overwrite a nearby variable.

The problem is I don't know how to type the address values I need, `\x84` and `\x04` etc. If I were able to use bash I would `echo -ne "\x84"` or use a C hex array but I can't do that kind of thing here.

I've tried using a hex to ASCII converter and copying the binary character and also using expect script to send the binary values but both have the same issue. x84 adds an extra char and x04 won't write at all.

Any idea the best way to reliably write values to memory that can't be represented by ASCII characters over ssh on a Unix tty?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking how to type control characters on the terminal, or how the C program writes what it read into memory?

Comment: If you're operating on binary data, you shouldn't be using `fgets()` and friends. That's for reading text data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone right now. Possibly the former. If I write AAAA I get x41x41x41x41 etc in memory. If I write \x84 it writes x78x38x34 etc. I'm having trouble writing the hex value I want as fgets interprets everything as ascii and doesn't seem to allow escape sequences.

Comment: That's not really a programming question, then, it's more about how to use Unix.

Comment: Are you sure you used `expect` correctly?  Of course `fgets` doesn't process escape sequences inside the program using it.  Neither does `strcpy`, or `scanf("%s")`.  I didn't fully read your last comment until after making an edit, so I think I actually answered half of your question by editing it.

Comment: the function: `fgets()` cannot overflow the input buffer unless the server programmer typed an invalid length for the buffer.  I suspect you are thinking of `gets()`.  In fact that is why `gets()` is nolonger part of the C language.

Comment: I'm not directly overflowing fgets, the overflow is possible because the fgets buffer is larger than the one it will be copied into.  I'll update my question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For high characters, you can probably copy/paste.

e.g. `echo -ne "\x84" | xclip -i` then middle-click in your terminal emulator, if your desktop is also running Linux.  (**or maybe not, see below**).  Or `echo ... | ssh user@host` could work.

`ssh -T` or the equivalent in any other terminal emulator might also be an option, to "Disable pseudo-terminal allocation", so the program on the remote side would have its `stdin` be a pipe from sshd, rather than a pseudo-terminal, I think.  This would disable stuff like `^s` and `^v` being special, I think.

Conversely, `echo foo | ssh -tt` will force it to request a tty on the remote side, even though you're piping stuff into ssh.

---

A less-intrusive way to make sure binary data over SSH gets through the TTY layer and to the `stdin` of the receiving program is to precede every byte with a control-`v` (hex 0x16).

As Barmar points out, that's the literal-next character (`lnext` in `stty -a` output).  You can use it before *every* byte of your payload; it's stripped by the TTY layer in the receiver even before ordinary characters.

```
# LANG=C sed to replace every byte with ^V byte
# using bash $'' to put a literal control-V on sed's command line
echo "hello" | LANG=C sed $'s/./\x16&/g' | hd
        16 68 16 65 16 6c 16 6c  16 6f 0a                 |.h.e.l.l.o.|
```

You can test all this locally by typing into `hexdump -C` (aka `hd`).  Just run it in a terminal, and type or paste some stuff, then control-D until it exits.

```
$ echo -ne "\x01\xff\x99" | LANG=C sed $'s/./\x16&/g' | hd
00000000  16 01 16 ff 16 99                                 |......|
00000006
      # yup, correct bytes from sed
$ echo -ne "\x01\xff\x99" | LANG=C sed $'s/./\x16&/g' | xclip -i
$ LANG=C hd
^A��     (middle click, return, control-d)
00000000  01 ef bf bd ef bf bd 0a                           |........|
     # nope, that munged my data :/

$ xclip -o | hd
00000000  16 01 16 ff 16 99                                 |......|
```

So the X selection itself is correct, but it's getting munged either by Konsole as I paste, or by the TTY layer on the way from Konsole to `hexdump`?  The latter seems unlikely; probably it's a paste problem.  Konsole's "encoding" setting is UTF-8.  It doesn't seem to have a plain ASCII setting.

Maybe try with `LANG=C xterm` or something, or just script `expect` correctly to send actual binary data to `ssh`, rather than escape codes.

---

`fgets` of course does not process escape sequences, any more than `strcpy` would.  In general C functions don't; but in C the *compiler* processes escape sequences inside *string literals* at compile time.

Comment: ' Precede every byte with a control-v (hex 0x16)' worked perfectly for me. I used a pexpect script to send the hex.

Nice extension on Barmar's answer.  Upvoted both. 

'it's stripped by the TTY layer in the receiver even before ordinary characters' very interesting morsel of information, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can write characters in the range `0x00` to `0x1f` by typing control characters on the keyboard. Hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key while typing a character in the third column of this [ASCII Chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) to get the corresponding code in the first column.

Some control characters have special meaning to the terminal driver (e.g. <kbd>Ctl-c</kbd> to kill the process), you can type them literally by preceding with <kbd>Ctl-v</kbd>.

And you can get `0x7f` by typing <kbd>Ctl-v</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> (this is the backward delete character, which might be labeld <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, not the forward delete that may be in a separate keypad).

I'm not sure if there's any easy way to type characters above this. Depending on the settings in your terminal emulator, you might be able to get the high bit set by holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while typing the corresponding ASCII character. E.g. <kbd>Alt-A</kbd> would send `0xc1` (`0x80 | 0x41`).

Comment: You might also be able to copy/paste data with the high bit set, if you can overcome any UTF-8 assumptions in your terminal.