# How to pass non-printable ASCII byte to STDIN file-descriptor in x86_64 assembler (yasm)

Tags: ascii, x86-64, stdin, yasm, non-printing-characters

## Problem

Suppose I have a program in `x86_64` assembler `yasm` (see below) that requests input from a user via `SYS_read` system service at some moment. This output is treated as byte-number further in the program. User easely could provide all numbers corresponding to the printable ASCII symbols i.e. from `0x20` to `0x7f` (maybe some more). But how to provide `0x90` for example?

## Possible solution for a few characters

I could use the following combination to provide the desired number:

```
<C-S-u> 0 0 9 0
```

But this solution may be tedious when it is necessary to enter many characters.

## Program fragment

Here is that part of the program that responsible for the reading from STDIN.

```
readChar:
    mov     rax, SYS_read
    mov     rdi, STDIN
    lea     rsi, byte [rbp - 1] 
    mov     rdx, 1
    syscall
```

Comment: Redirect input from a file you create with a hex editor.  Or with bash `printf '\x90\x91' | ./my_program`.  Try stuff with `printf '\x90' | hexdump -C` to check what bytes you're printing.

Comment: This gives segmentation fault.

Comment: Then your program has a bug, and you should debug it with GDB and `strace`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Comment: Sending binary data over a TTY is tricky, so piping input from something else is normal.  But if you really want to use a TTY, see [Write non-ASCII characters to stdin of a progam on a tty (over ssh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329447/write-non-ascii-characters-to-stdin-of-a-progam-on-a-tty-over-ssh) for workarounds that might work for you, too (e.g. prepend a `^V` before every byte of what you paste)

Comment: @PeterCordes, seems you're right about a bug. I have tried it with minimal example and it worked.

Comment: Oh, I must include the newline `\n` character at the end of string, otherwise there is an infinte loop :)